# Non-exhaustive patterns in function with tuples HASKELL

Tags: haskell

```
regiuleishon :: (Bool, Integer) -> Integer
regiuleishon (True, _) = 0
reguleishon (False, x) | x >= 0 = 1
                       | otherwise = -1
```

Why doesn't this code work? The program says:

> Exception: pruebas.hs:13:1-26: Non-exhaustive patterns in function regiuleishon

I try to put `-> (True, 2)` and the response is 0 but if I put `(False, 200)` :( the exception appears

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `regiuleishon` is not `reguleishon`, so `reguleishon (False, x) ...` is a new function declaration leading to the code having 2 different functions neither of which have exhaustive patterns.

Name the second pattern correctly:

```hs
regiuleishon :: (Bool, Integer) -> Integer
regiuleishon (True, _) = 0
regiuleishon (False, x) | x >= 0 = 1
                        | otherwise = -1
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo: the second line says `regiuleishon`, but the third line says `reguleishon` - missing an `i` after `g`.

So to the compiler, it looks like you're done defining the function named `regiuleishon` and moved on to defining a totally different function named `reguleishon`. The first function only covers the `True` case, so the pattern match is incomplete. And the second function only covers the `False` case, so its match is incomplete as well.